# How do the competing definitions for lattices relate?

Tags: lattice-orders, integer-lattices

> **Definition 1:** A lattice is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^m$ for some $m$.

> **Definition 2:** A lattice is the set of all integer linear combinations of some set of basis vectors $\mathbf{b}_1,\dots,\mathbf{b}_n$:
>   $$
> \left\{\sum_i a_i\mathbf{b}_i\,\middle|\,a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
> $$

> **Definition 3:** A lattice is a partially ordered set in which any two elements have a unique supremum and infimum.

Wikipedia also has other definitions that go straight over my head. My question is: which of these definitions are equivalent, which are special cases of the other, and why so?

Answer (score 1):

The first two definitions are equivalente for lattice (in group theory) and the third definition is regarding lattices in order theory. Both are called lattice but are two different things. One kind are defined as discrete subgroups of R and the other kind are defined in terms of an order with a specific sup/inf opertion.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to Juan Ramirez answer the (sketch of the) proof that 2 is a particular case of 1.

Let's denote $L=\left\{\sum_i a_i\mathbf{b}_i\,\middle|\,a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. Define the map $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\mapsto L$ by $f(a_1,\dots, a_n)=\sum_i a_i\mathbf{b}_i$. It has inverse $f^{-1}(\sum_i a_i\mathbf{b}_i)=(a_1,\dots, a_n)$. Here, the fact that $\{b_1,\dots, b_n\}$ is basis is important, since otherwise $f$ might not be injective (if they weren't linearly independent) or might not be surjective (if they don't generate $\mathbb{R}^n$).

It is clear that $f$ is a group homomorphism, since it preserves componentwise sum. Hence, both structures are isomorphic for $m=n$.

For the converse, there are some answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881501/equivalent-definitions-of-a-lattice-in-a-real-vector-space-of-finite-dimension).

Comment: This only shows that a lattice according to definition 2 is also a lattice according to definition 1, but not the other way around.

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff I guess you're saying this because Definition 1 says "for some $m$", well, take that $m$ (which is unique) and do the same. The $n$ of Definition 2 doen't have to be the same as the Definition 1, since in Definition 1 could be any $n\geq m$.

Comment: No, I'm saying this because for the direction $1\to 2$ one needs to come up with a finite list of basis vectors whose integer linear combinations reproduce the entire group.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'll link an answer to that.