# Equivalent definition of lattice in complex plane

Tags: abstract-algebra

The definition of a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ that I'm aware of is the following: Let $w_1=u_1+v_1i$ and $w_2=u_2+v_2i$ be two nonzero complex numbers such that the vectors $(u_1,v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The the set $L=\{mw_1+nw_2\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a lattice.

Why is this equivalent to the definition that a discrete additive subgroup $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ if $L\otimes \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{C}$?

In particular, I think I can work out why if we have $L$ of the form $L=\{mw_1+nw_2\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ as described above, then $L\otimes \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{C}$. But why does the converse hold?

Comment: I assume $L$ is an additive subgroup of $\Bbb C$. I think the converse is not true, it might have more than 2 generating vectors.

Comment: @Berci $L$ is a discrete additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$. I made the edit.

Comment: Here's a proof of a more general fact: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2296913/54092 .. the statement $L \otimes \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{C}$ is a somewhat weird (and slightly incorrect, I think, if you are pedantic about equality of sets) way to say that the subgroup spans $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space.